# Used Kedestroy and now can't use Kinit to authenticate myself

Tags: kerberos

I've been using kerberos for about a month now with 0 problems whatsoever. Today I decided to test out the kdestroy command because I had been reading about it for a little. Unfortunately now I can't use kinit to authenticate myself!

When I use the kinit command and type in my password I get this error message

```
kinit: krb5_get_init_creds: Error from KDC: CLIENT_NOT_FOUND
```

I'm not sure why? I don't understand. I thought kdestroy just wiped out the ticket that I was currently under. I didn't think it would disallow me from every authenticating again?

Comment: are you using your full username and domain (e.g. "`knit noah@FNAL.GOV`") or are you just trying "`kinit noah`"?  If the latter, try using the former.

Comment: Yep I'm an idiot, the wrong username was being used. Thanks!

Comment: I am glad the net if full of idiots doing the same dumb stuff as me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`kdestroy`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/kdestroy.1.html) simply removes a credential or destroys the current ticket file, just as you were guessing.

I made one guess above as to what might be going on (where you need to use the full domain name... use uppercase for the domain portion), and another possible symptom is that your username doesn't exist or it's incorrect.  [It could also indicate a DNS issue](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463167.aspx).

Comment: It was my name that was incorrect, didn't see that it was auto suggesting an incorrect username, thank you!